# sql query get parent only if conditions met

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a list of parent ids.

What I want to do is only get parent ids when the child types hit certain values.

so something like this -

```
select parentid from table
where parentid in (select parentid from table where name like '%123%' and name not like '%abc%'
```

each child has a reference to parent.
so if I had a list like so

```
parent1
  123
  abc
parent2
  123
  def
parent3
  123
  abc
```

What I would get in return is only the parent ID where childs did not contain abc

```
parent2
  123
  def
```

Comment: what does your table look like? are you only looking for one level deep child records? what if a child of a child records satisfy the where condition,, do you want both parents in that case or just the immediate parent of that record?  you need to show some sample data and a desired output and please make sure the same data addresses the above conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use `NOT EXISTS` to do this:

```
SELECT parentid
FROM TABLE t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT t2.parentid
        FROM TABLE t2
        WHERE t1.parentid = t2.parentid
          AND t2.NAME LIKE '%abc%'
        );
```

Comment: I think that should be `AND t2.NAME NOT LIKE '%123%'`.

Comment: @GentlemanMax I think you brought up a good point though, he doesn't need to check for both `123` and `abc` at the same time in the same column.

Comment: For this example you're probably right, though in general he may want to have a filter where he wants to exclude based on multiple criteria so having both conditions may be good for refernce purposes.

Comment: Yeah `having` is only used when you are using some kind of aggregate function. But, I agree if he has multiple conditions to check then it should be another filter line in the where clause.